# redux/createSelector keeps re-rendering in react-native app

Tags: react-native, redux

I'm building a social media app in react native. I'm using react-redux with redux-toolkit and flashlist, along with other libraries.

My redux state (simplified) looks like this: (postState is the name of the reducer)

```
{
    feeds: {},
    posts: [],
    accounts: []
}
```

When I fetch the home feed, all the posts are fetched. To prevent duplicate data (a user can have multiple posts on the home feed), I split the data into posts and accounts. Every post is stored with only the account ID (and not the full account data). I store an array of ids in the feed object. The key of each array is the id of the specific feed.

```
{
    feed: {
        home: [1,2,3,4],
        user_1: [2,4],
        ...
    }
}
```

When fetching the posts for the feed, I have the following code:

```
const getFeedid = (state, feedId) => feedId;
const getFeeds = state => state.feeds;
const getPosts = state => state.posts;
const getAccounts = state => state.accounts;

const getPostsForFeed = createSelector([getFeeds, getPosts, getAccounts], (feedId, feeds, posts, accounts) => {
    const ids = feeds[feedId];

    let postsArr = posts.filter(e => ids.includes(e.postId));
    let arr = [];

    postsArr.forEach((post) => {
        const account = accounts.find(e => e.accountId === post.accountId);

        return {
            ...post,
            account
        };
    });

    return postsArr;
});

const posts = useSelector(state => getPostsForFeed(state.postsState, 'home'), shallowEqual);
```

In a flashlist, I display these items.

```
// probably not neccessary?
const memoizedPosts = useMemo(() => posts, [posts]);

const renderItems = useCallback(({item}) => {
    return (<Post item={item} />);
}, []);

const keyExtractor = useCallback(item => item.postId.toString(), []);

const [viewableIndexes, setViewableIndexes] = useState([]);

const onViewableItemsChanged = useCallback(({viewableItems}) => {
    setViewableIndexes(viewableItems.map(e => e.index));
}, []);

<FlashList
    keyExtractor={keyExtractor}
    renderItems={renderItems}
    items={memoizedPosts}
    onViewableItemsChanged={onViewableItemsChanged}
/>
```

**What is the problem?**

When I scroll up or down, the viewableIndexes state changes. This is normal. But the posts in the redux state keep refreshing.

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log('posts in redux changed');
}, [posts]);
```

When I add this useEffect to my code, whenever I scroll up or down in the flashlist, the useEffect-code is triggered multiple times. I don't get it, because the content of the redux state is not changed, only the viewableIndex-state is changed.

The `<Post />`-component is in a React.memo().

**My question is:**

why does this useEffect code runs whenever I scroll, because this means that "posts" has changed whenever I scroll. I'm starting to learn createSelector (I never used it before but I found out this would be a good use case). Maybe there is something wrong in my createSelector? I'm not changing the redux-state in other components while scrolling. I'm literally only scrolling, I'm not changing redux state (but I am changing a state in the component with the flashlist itself).

When I remove this useState-change, it works.

Comment: It's a bit difficult to say with certainty what may be the issue in your code. Please [edit] to include a more complete and cohesive [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue may arise because this line is placed inside the component:

```
const getPostsForFeed = createSelector(...
```

which results `getPostsForFeed` being recreated every time the content renders, so the memorized state of `input-selector` is lost. Have a look at https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#using-memoizing-selectors .

Comment: OP's code example is incomplete, are you just assuming that `getPostsForFeed` is declared within a React component? You might not be wrong, but I don't see strong evidence to support the claim in your answer.

Comment: @DrewReese, yes you're right. It's hard to know the exact problem without seeing the actual code. I was trying to give a clue so he/she could solve it quickly if possible. I intended to comment rather than answer, but I couldn't with my low reputation. Sadly.

Comment: I see. I'd probably qualify the claim with something along the lines of "assuming X is defined in Y, then Z" if you have a strong suspicion the assumption is correct.

Comment: Edited. Thanks. I'll be more careful in composing replies.

Comment: No worries. Sometime authors don't give us much to go on and guesswork is involved.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed answer. I was not able to answer sooner. It's correct, when placing the code outside of the component, everything works as expected! Thank you very much.